# Query by Java MongoDB driver is 40 times slower compared to Mongo Shell

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

My MongoDB is more than 40 times slower with Java Driver compared to Mongo shell. I have 1000000 documents(with same schema) in 1 collection and 1 database.

Below Mongo Shell command took less than 1 milliseconds.

```
> db.basket.find({appleId : "appleId-312093"}).explain("executionStats")
```

This is part of the result.

```
"nReturned" : 1,
"executionTimeMillis" : 0,
"totalKeysExamined" : 1,
"totalDocsExamined" : 1,
...
"indexName" : "appleId"
...
```

Since I have index on appleId, it was very fast.
But with the below code using Java Driver, It took more than 42 milliseconds.

```
@Test
public void elapsedTimeMongoDriver() {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoCollection<Document> collection =  mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME).getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);

    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    Document doc = collection.find(eq("appleId", "appleId-329199"))
            .hint(eq("appleId", 1)).first();

    stopWatch.stop();

    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    System.out.println("Total Elapsed: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " milliseconds");
}
```

Further, when I used Spring Data MongoDB, below code took more than 500 milliseconds.

```
@Test
public void elapsedTimeSpringMongo() {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    Fruit fruit = mongoOperations.findOne(
            query(where("appleId").is("appleId-329199"))
            , Fruit.class
            , COLLECTION_NAME);
    stopWatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Total Elapsed: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds");
}
```

Is this just because I am using inefficient way to query document?
Or is there any way to query as fast as Mongo Shell does?

About indexing,

```
@Test
public void index() {
    IndexOperations indexOperations = mongoOperations.indexOps(COLLECTION_NAME);
    indexOperations.getIndexInfo().stream().forEach(i -> {
        i.getIndexFields().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    });
}
```

The output of above method is

```
...
IndexField [ key: appleId, direction: ASC, type: DEFAULT, weight: NaN]
...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Currently I am using,
Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, 
Spring 5.0.2, 
Spring Data MongoDB 2.0.2.RELEASE, 
Mongo Driver 3.5.0, and
Mongod 3.6.0

Comment: 1.mongo shell returns JSON directly, 2. Java driver transforms the JSON output to Document 3. Spring mongo transforms the Document to Model object, for these transformation it might've taken few mills

Comment: You should turn on the [profiling level](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) in mongodb and check the logs to see how long the query generated by your Spring application takes.

Comment: Did you execute Mongo shell command on the machine on which mongo-db is installed? Are you considering network time if db and java app are running on different instances? Please share configuration used to connect mongo-db for both the examples.